# Explanation for clobber list in extended GCC inline assembly executing the x87 FPATAN operation

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

The following code is in the **MinGW** [x86inline.h](http://www.willus.com/mingw/x87inline.h) file:

```
/*
** in-line atan2(y,x) function.
** Computes arctan(y/x).
*/
#define atan2(y,x) atan2_x87_inline(y,x)
double atan2_x87_inline(double y,double x);
extern __inline__ double atan2_x87_inline(double y,double x)
    {
    double result;
    __asm__ ("fpatan" : "=t" (result) : "0" (x), "u" (y) : "st(1)");
    return(result);
    }
```

As I understand, the x87 `fpatan` operation uses the `st(0)` and `st(1)` registers, overwrites the contents of the `st(1)` register, and then pops the top register.

So why is only `st(1)` included in the clobber list, as opposed to `st(0)` as well?

**EDIT**: In fact, why would it need a clobber list at all since `st(0)` and `st(1)` should be known to the compiler via the `"t"` and `"u"` constraints. Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is explained in the [GCC documentation on inline asm](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) (see section 6.41.2 about i386 floating point):

> Given a set of input registers that die in an asm, it is necessary to know which are implicitly popped by the asm, and which must be explicitly popped by GCC.
>
> An input register that is implicitly popped by the asm must be explicitly clobbered, unless it is constrained to match an output operand.

In this case, the `fpatan` operation pops both inputs and pushes the output, so we clobber `st(1)` to indicate this. We need to clobber only `st(1)` and not `st(0)` because `st(0)` is constrained to an output operand.